# Not allowing multiple Null values in an Access 2010 multi-column Index

Tags: indexing, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create a table in **Access 2010** which will not allow duplicates in two fields, but will allow nulls in one of those fields providing there is only a single null value (so no duplication of value/null).

My table fields are as below with the `ID` field set as a Primary Key and the plan is to not allow duplicates in `CostCode/TeamID` but `TeamID` can be Null once for each instance of a `CostCode`.

[image: Index Set Up]

The picture below shows that I can't add a `CostCode` and `TeamID` twice if they both have values, but I can add a `CostCode` twice with Null values in `TeamID`.

[image]

Is there anyway to achieve this?
I've read I could give TeamID a default value of an empty string (or 0 as that will never be a TeamID) but I'd like to use Null if possible as that is what the empty string or 0 would represent.

**EDIT:**
After the comment from JJ32 and a weekend to think it through I've gone with putting the TeamID value into a separate table.
I would then have a Many-2-Many join between `tbl_BranchDetail` and `tbl_CostCodes` and a Many-2-Many join between `tbl_CostCodeM2MJoin` and `tbl_Teams`.

[image]

This will remove Null values from occurring in either Many-2-Many table and my query will now read as:

```
SELECT       M2M.BranchID
            ,M2M.CostCodeID
            ,TM2M.TeamID
            ,CC.CostCode
            ,TM.TeamName
FROM        ((tbl_CostCodes CC INNER JOIN tbl_CostCodeM2MJoin M2M ON CC.ID = M2M.CostCodeID)
                               LEFT JOIN tbl_CostCodeToTeamM2MJoin TM2M ON (M2M.BranchID = TM2M.BranchID AND
                                                                           M2M.CostCodeID = TM2M.CostCodeID))
                               LEFT JOIN tbl_Teams TM ON TM2M.TeamID = TM.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to disallow duplicate nulls in a unique composite index since no two Nulls are ever considered equal.

So in your example above you'd have three unique rows, one with a combination of TBC/1 and two with a combination of TBC/null.

The only answer I know of, unfortunately, is to choose some non-null value to represent null in TeamID, and then display the result as empty within the application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply JJ32.  I was hoping it wouldn't be something like that.  I had a rethink over the weekend and I'm going to split the `TeamID` into a separate table.  Currently the `tbl_CostCodes` table has a M:M join with a `tbl_BranchDetail` table.  Some branches have more than one cost code (which is where the TeamID comes in) and some cost codes cover more than one branch.  So I've got a table listing `BranchID` and `CostCodeID` to achieve the M:M link between the tables.. if I create another to link the teams to the branch and cost code it should work...  I think.